# Gmail not working with the background data restriction

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, micromax-yu-yureka

My device is YU YUREKA with android 4.4.4 and Cyanogenmod 11.0

Restriction of background data in android devices is very much in now-a-days and I always use it. But recently I am facing problem with the Gmail app. Sometimes it is not working with the data restriction even when it is not a background process.

Therefore to get my mails I have to un-check the data restriction option every time, for which other apps are consuming unwanted data.

Is there any way to make Gmail working again with the restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail app is used to show only the mails that is received by another core app called Google play services using synchronization that needs background data connection,When we open Gmail app then the play services app get restricted by DATA restriction.
I want to say that some app like Play Store and Gmail will not work If you have restriction on background data.
I think it will help